# "Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context"

Tags: html, css, html5, validación

Estoy aprendiendo desarrollo web y estoy validando mi código en el NU HTML checker, pero me lanza este error:
**Element `style` not allowed as child of element `body` in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <title></title>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img.png" alt="" height="50" width="50"></a>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator?uri=www.google.com"><imgstyle="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!"/></a>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: url("img.jpg");
        }
        div {
            background:url("img.png");
        }
        header {
            color:#fff;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        header p {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
```

Y desde acá empezaría el `body`. Ya he validado el CSS pero durante la validación del HTML me sale eso. Alguien puede decirme cuál es el error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

los elementos

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="img.png" alt="" height="50" width="50"></a>
<a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator?uri=www.google.com"><img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!"/></a>
```

que tienes dentro de la etiqueta `<head>`, van en la etiqueta `<body>`, no en el `head`, y fíjate que la segunda etiqueta `a`, dentro tiene una imagen `<img>` donde tienes unido **imgstyle**, separalos , en la respuesta te lo dejo corregido

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! :) Ya está resuelto el error

Comment: De nada, aquí estamos para ayudar